# how to convert text file to Excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, text

I need to convert text file to Excel file.

the text file follows the following format:

First row

```
05100079 0000001502 5 01   2 070 1924    02 06 1994 C508 2 8500 3 8500 3 3 1 1 012 10    0 98 00                       4 8 8 9                                                                                               0    40       01              2 15      26000 1748 C508       116 102 3  09 98 013 1 1 0 1 10 10       0 09003     50060 50060 0 0  369 99 9       1 4 4 5 8                          0 0181                        1 80 00 01 0            9 9       8        1 0 00 00 020 0
```

Second row

```
05100095 0000001502 2 01   2 059 1917    02 03 1977 C504 2 8500 3 8500 3 9 1 1                   54-11-0999-00         2     9                                                                                               0    90       01              2 12      26000 1744 C504       116 102 3  09 98 013 1 1 0 2             0 09011     50060 50060 0    36   9 9       1 9 9 5 8                          0 3161                                                9 9       8                  020 0             `
```

convert text file to Excel file, and keeping space between column.

expected result: expected result: convert text file to Excel file, and keeping the spaces as blanks columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer come from the [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557058/how-to-convert-a-text-file-to-excel-with-python)

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet('First Sheet')  # Add a sheet

f = open('testval.txt', 'r+')

data = f.readlines() # read all lines at once
for i in range(len(data)):
  row = data[i].split()  # This will return a line of string data, you may need to convert to other formats depending on your use case

  for j in range(len(row)):
    ws.write(i, j, row[j])  # Write to cell i, j

book.save('testval' + '.xls')
f.close()
```

In the case that you want all white space as column you can use openpyxl package to handle more than 256 columns :

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active


f = open('testval.txt', 'r+')

data = f.readlines()
spaces = ""
for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i].split(" ")  
    ws.append(row)
wb.save("testval2.xlsx")
```

Comment: True, it converts the file, but deleting the space on each line, I want to keep the space on each line?!

Comment: I changed the answer to add each space as a column if you want to make bunch of the spaces as one column, you need to go trough the loop and and collect them. if you have problem about that leave a message.

Comment: The code is executed and there are no errors, but no new Excel file is created !!

Comment: I tried the code and it works for me, so I assume it must be something about the permissions or file addresses, have you tried to put the program and first file in the same folder?!

Comment: thx @sean Meyer, The implementation is done, but when applied to a large file, the memory becomes full and the conversion is not complete! Is there another way?

Comment: if your file is big, maybe making csv file is better solution than excel file (less tag code included), but I am afraid that it is not the case, because if your file is so big, none of them going to be opened by the excel program :( (excel use Memory to open the files )